# Change the dimensions of many images with one move in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, images, dimensions

I want to change the dimensions (height and width) of some images that I have inserted into a Word document, and do it automatically and not one by one(right click and size...).

The images have the same initial size.  They are all going to the same new size and preserving the aspect ratio without cropping. They were not previously resized or otherwise modified on the page.  The images I want to change have the same category of caption.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Change from what to what?  Are they all the same initial size?  Going to the same size?  Preserving the aspect ratio?  Any cropping involved?  Were they resized or otherwise previously manipulated on the page?

Comment: Yes they have the same initial size. Going to the same size and preserving the ratio without cropping. They weren't resized on  the page

Comment: Have you tried selecting all of them, select size from menu and edit it?